# DataTriggers and ComboBox in WPF

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datatrigger, itemssource

How can I use `DataTriggers` to change the color of a ComboBox when its `ItemsSource` contains no items?

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyData}">
    <ComboBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderThicknes" Value="2"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.Style>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: Have you tried `<DataTrigger Binding="MyData.Count" Value="0">`?

Comment: Or `<Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="False">`

Comment: Make sure you don't set the background in line with your combobox definition as the Style will NOT work! Also my first comment should read `Binding="{Binding MyData.Count}"`.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the template for a combobox there is a bit of a problem lurking there in the form of a value set on the togglebutton template.

Right click your combo and use properties> Miscellaneous to extract the template.
Take a look in there for the border called "templateroot":

```
  <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
        <Border x:Name="templateRoot" 
                 BorderBrush="#FFACACAC" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                 <Border.Background>
```

You will need to add an xmlns:
     xmlns:Themes="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero2"
Change that BorderBrush to also bind to Templatedparent

```
 <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
         <Border x:Name="templateRoot" 
                  BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
```

You can then see it change.
Here, I've given it a default value of green so it's obvious the changes are doing anything:

```
        <ComboBox.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Green" />
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding HasItems, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
```

Alternatively you could use:

```
  <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ItemsSource.Count, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="0">
         <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
         </DataTrigger>
```

or

```
 <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
  </Trigger>
```

The above is tested on windows 10.

Comment: Why `<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding HasItems, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">` when you have `<Trigger Property="HasItems">`? Makes no sense.